# Is it possible to remove a Ktor route programmatically?

Tags: routes, ktor

Ktor makes it easy to add routes

```
     route("/hello", HttpMethod.Get) {
        handle {
            call.respondText("Hello")
        }
    }
    route("{..}", HttpMethod.Get) {
    handle {
           call.respondText("Everything else")
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to REMOVE the first route on the fly?
We'd like to disable the first so that the path gets picked up by the second

Answer (score 0):

The `Route` object doesn't have the capabilities to remove its children. There is only a dirty and not robust (it relies on the implementation) solution to cast route's children to `MutableList`:

```
val routing = server.application.feature(Routing)
val children = routing.children as MutableList<Route>
children.removeAt(0)
```